# Display chosen filter in separate cell

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to display the chosen value from a drop-down list in a separate cell.

For example, if my drop-down allowed me to filter by days of the week, I want whichever day I've chosen to display in a separate cell.  As filters are changed, the separate cell should change automatically.

Can anyone help?

Many thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: A lot of on-line research, with not much luck so far!  I've tried linking the cells using Properties within the Development tab, but was unsuccessful.  Also tried some minor VBA, but this didn't work either.  I'm no Excel expert, but have tried everything I can think of - am hoping someone can help me out... please!

Answer (score 1):

Allright Claire, it took me a while, but I hope this helps... You would definitely need to resort to VBA. Paste the following code into a new module in your VBA Project, as to create a User Defined Function.

```
Function udfAFCriteria(rngCaller As Range) As String
Application.Volatile

Dim rngFilter As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet, f As Filter

Set ws = rngCaller.Parent

If ws.AutoFilterMode = False Then
udfAFCriteria = "No filter selected"

Exit Function

End If

   Set f = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(1)
   Set rngFilter = f.Parent.Range

For i = 1 To rngFilter.Columns.Count
    If rngFilter.Cells(1, i).Column = rngCaller.Column Then Exit For
Next i

    Set f = ws.AutoFilter.Filters(i)
        If f.On Then
        Select Case f.Operator
    Case 0
        udfAFCriteria = f.Criteria1
    Case XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd
        udfAFCriteria = f.Criteria1 & " and " & f.Criteria2
    Case XlAutoFilterOperator.xlOr
        udfAFCriteria = f.Criteria1 & " or " & f.Criteria2
    Case XlAutoFilterOperator.xlBottom10Items
        udfAFCriteria = "Bott x (" & f.Criteria1 & ")"
    Case XlAutoFilterOperator.xlBottom10Percent
        udfAFCriteria = "Bott x% (" & f.Criteria1 & ")"
    Case XlAutoFilterOperator.xlTop10Items
        udfAFCriteria = "Top x (" & f.Criteria1 & ")"
    Case XlAutoFilterOperator.xlTop10Percent
        udfAFCriteria = "Top x% (" & f.Criteria1 & ")"
    Case Else
        udfAFCriteria = "Operator Unknown"
End Select
    Else
        udfAFCriteria = ""
End If

End Function
```

Then in a cell B1 write =udfAFCriteria(A1) which will give you the selected filter (Assuming you have a filter on cell A1). Also see the example below.

[image]

Credits for the code go to Greg Truby from mrexcel.com. I modified it slightly. Good luck

Comment: Ok, so in column A, I have data validation to select a day of the week.  The spreadsheet info is not in order, so could be a list of... Monday (A1), Monday (A2), Tuesday (A3), Thursday (A4), Sunday (A5), Monday (A6), etc.  The column also has a filter, to select a day (say, Sunday for example).  If I use a simple cell reference (=A1), this cell is actually no longer visible due to the filter.  I would need it to display the value in cell (A5), or whatever was selected from the filter.  Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Excellent!  This works perfectly!  Sincere thanks to you and Greg Truby for all of your time and help!

Comment: You're welcome! I'd appreciate it if you could vote the answer as being helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, if you have some kind of ID in one column.

If none is selected

[image: If none is selected]

If one is selected

[image: If one is selected]

If more than one is selected

[image: If more than one is selected]

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [answer] a question.

Answer (score 0):

So I used this excellent code and whilst it works, I'm getting an = proceceding the displayed text. I've gone through the code and there is no "=" or '=' anywhere.

Any ideas?

Thans so much

Comment: This is not an answer. Please ask a question on your own.